# Where did the Google Sets feature go?

Tags: google-docs

Where did Google Sets go? I can't find it.

Did it move to another Google app or within one of the options inside Google Docs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Google Sets was shut down in September 2011](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/08/google-sets-will-be-shut-down.html).

You can closely recreate this feature using Google Docs Spreadsheets when you [build a keyword list](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tI_4PearMTU).

Follow these sets after opening up a fresh document in Google Spreadsheets:

1. Enter values in a single column
2. Select all values in this column

   [image: spreadsheet with seed values]
3. Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>
4. Click and drag the blue dot that appears lower bottom right of this selection
5. The rest of the list will now be filled in with extended guesses using the Google Sets Labs.

   [image: populated guesses using google sets data]

Comment: Pretty awesome.

Comment: It should be `option` key on Mac. `Cmd` repeats the selected items.

Comment: Sadly, this feature is not available in newer Google Spreadsheets https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3543688?hl=en

Comment: Well that's just the pits @mrm